# How can I add React web components to a parent component dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, web-component

Let's say I have a bunch of React web components

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  return (<div>A</div>)
}
const ComponentB = () => {
  return (<div>B</div>)
}
const ComponentC = () => {
  return (<div>C</div>)
}
const ComponentD = () => {
  return (<div>D</div>)
}
const ComponentE = () => {
  return (<div>E</div>)
}
```

and I have a parent component that renders some of them.

```
export default function () {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ count: 0, initialized: false, components: [ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC] });
  return (
    <FlexLayout>
      {state.components.map((comp, i) => React.createElement(comp, { key: i }))}
    </FlexLayout>
  );
}
```

This works as I can see my three components A, B, and C are rendered properly. Next, I add a button to add new items dynamically.

```
export default function () {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ components: [ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC] });
  const handler = () => 
  {
    const list = state.components.slice(0);
    list.push(ComponentD);
    setState ({ components : list })
  }

  return (
    <FlexLayout>
      <button onClick={() => setState(handler)}>Add Component</button>
      {state.components.map((comp, i) => React.createElement(comp, { key: i  }))}
    </FlexLayout>
  );
}
```

This also works when I click the button for the first time. I can see that I have added ComponentD . However, If I try to add one more instance of ComponentD  the app crashes with the following error:

[image]

What is causing this loss of scope where my components are no longer available to the parent?

Comment: The problems seems to be your button onClick handler. It should be referencing the handler function directly but instead you’re passing that handler function to setState

Comment: Thanks, tried this {() => handler } but it didn't work. Instead, adding this worked {() => setState({ components: [...state.components, ComponentD] } as any)}. But why didn't the handler version work, I wonder.

Comment: Just add this: onClick={handler}

Comment: If you do this onClick={()=>handler} you are just passing an anonymous function that upon being called will return your handler. onClick={handler} will pass the function reference you want which will then be called in response to clicks

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the answer. I really appreciate the help! I do understand what was going on after you first mentioned it but thanks for the more detailed explanation, maybe it will help someone else as well.

Comment: No problem! Keep going :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some feedback:

- Storing entire components in state is an anti pattern. Instead, store IDs in the state. Simpler state will reduce likelihood of bugs.
- as [@Mary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2992618/mary) said, your handler was incorrectly assigned.

Here's a working example:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  return (<div>A</div>)
}
const ComponentB = () => {
  return (<div>B</div>)
}
const ComponentC = () => {
  return (<div>C</div>)
}
const ComponentD = () => {
  return (<div>D</div>)
}

const componentMap = {
  a: ComponentA,
  b: ComponentB,
  c: ComponentC,
  d: ComponentD,
}

export default function () {
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([
    'a','b','c',
  ]);
  const handler = () => {
    setComponents ( [...components, 'd'] );
  }

  return (
    <FlexLayout>
      <button onClick={handler}>Add Component</button>
      {components.map(ID => {
        const Component = componentMap[ID];
        return <Component key={ID}/>
      })}
    </FlexLayout>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/romilton/pen/VwKvmve?editors=1111)